# Regarding deleting a record from database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database

I want to delete only those roll no that are present in the database. When the user enters a roll no that is not present in the database the system should give an error like rollno is not present in the database. In short, when the user enters the rollno the system must check that rollno is present or not if present then delete it or else it must give an error rollno not present Please help me with this

```
con = None
    try:
        con = connect("std.db")
        
        sql = "delete from student where rno = '%d' "
        cursor = con.cursor()
        rno = int(delete_rno_entry.get())
        cursor.execute(sql % (rno))
        con.commit()
        showinfo("Done" , "Record Deleted")
        delete_rno_entry.delete(0,END)
        delete_rno_entry.focus()
        
            

        
        
    except Exception as e:
        con.rollback()
        showerror("Issue" , e)
        delete_rno_entry.delete(0,END)
        delete_rno_entry.focus()
    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please be more specific on exactly what issue you are facing. Just saying "please help me accomplish this goal" isn't a question.

Comment: Can't you like check the response for the executed query? Does it return anything (like how many rows were affected)? Then you will know if the command did something or not and throw an error if needed. Or is just success/fail and nothing else? Then I guess you can execute another SQL before the DELETE like 'SELECT 1 FROM student WHERE rno = ...' and check if it returned anything.